# FileTransfer Permission issue on Android 6 (API 23) with ngCordova

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, ngcordova

**Question/Issue:**

I am getting a permission error doing the following:

*(Note: I have tried using `videoData[0].fullPath` and `videoData[0].localURL` and `videoData[0].toURL()` like the docs suggested which didn't make sense to me, but all failed to work.)*

```
$cordovaCapture.captureVideo(options).then(function(videoData) {
    // Video Captures works, however when I try to upload I get permission error below.
    $cordovaFileTransfer.upload(baseUrl + '/api/users/upload', videoData[0].fullPath, options, true)
        .then(function(result) {
            // this never triggers
        }, function(err) {
            // here I get permission open failed:EACCES (Permission denied)
            $scope.debug= err;
        });
});
```

Am I missing a step here? I tested my API and It handles uploads fine when using Postman. I would expect it to prompt me using the new permission model to ask if I want it to allow it to access my storage, however it never accomplishes this.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: serverUrl that is passed to cordovaFileTransfer  is correct ?  path is /upload and ful path directly. So '/' in between. can you check the url once

Comment: Is this issue only on Android 6 ? Is it working fine with lower versions?

Comment: @bharathv The only device I have to test this with is running Android 6 (API 23). From what I researched this is only related to the permission changes in Android 6. But I am not 100% certain.

Comment: You can install in lower version and test. If there is no problem with server url then it should work in android lower version. If it works in lower version. Then i would tell you the approach to solve. Because I dont know the server url that you are pointing. So check in lower version and let me know

Comment: Can you please provide the full `err` output and the actual full path to your file?

Comment: Have you tried whitelisting your server url in config.xml and CSP? https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/

Comment: @Fostah Is it solved?

Comment: install latest cordova-plugin-file and then cordova-plugin-file-transfer. I think there was a bug on cordova-plugin-file-transfer that has an old cordova-plugin-file dependency.

Comment: @Fostah Faced similar issue with folder creation in Android Marshamallow. It was an issue with cordova file plugin 4.1. Please find the issue link as follows - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-10798 So try using latest cordova file plugin transfer which uses latest cordova file plugin (4.2.x) dependency. It should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried the same and it works fine in android 6.0

1. Install the latest cordova-plugin-file-transfer (1.5.1 version)
2. In your code, you are passing same options to capture and also upload. Try to change the options.
   Refer https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-file-transfer

   ```
     fileTransferOptions = {
            'fileKey'   : 'files',
            'fileName'  : FILE_NAME,
           'chunkedMode': false
       }

    $cordovaFileTransfer.upload(serverUrl, videoData[0].fullPath, fileTransferOptions)
               .then(function (data) {
                   console.log('success');
               }, function (err) {console.log('error', err)});
   ```
3. If permission for storage is not prompted, then permission would not have been enabled. (You can add extra java code for allowing storage access always) For now, you can turn on the storage permission from mobile Settings -> Apps -> goto selected app and click on permission, turn on storage access.
4. Check whether serverUrl to which you are uploading file is correct or not.
5. Whitelist the server url.

   `<acess origin="YOUR_SERVER_URL"/>'
    /*Network accesss enable*/
   <access origin="http://*/*"/>

   <access origin="https://*/*"/>`

Comment: I was able to get it working manually triggering the permissions like you said in step 2. The problem is the file transfer plugin doesn't seem to prompt the file storage permission. I still need to add the network access permissions. I will test that today and see if that solve the problem and accept the answer. Th\anks!

Comment: If you want you can externally invoke permissions for the app.

Comment: Its file storage permission that is actually effecting and not the network access. So if it continues you can externally invoke permission.